# When does the minimap arrow pointing to a bounty objective appear?

Tags: diablo-iii

It seems to appear when you get near enough. But also in other cases, for which I can't guess a pattern yet. It could be after some time spent in the map, or after some percentage of the map has been discovered ...

Comment: I was wondering this also. I was searching for a cursed chest and was running entirely the wrong way and it appeared. Never went close to the objective but I did explore a lot of the map.

Comment: I suspect it is connected to a secondary objective "Kill x enemies in the area", but I am not sure.

Comment: Could be connected, but it's certainly not appearing systematically  at the time you complete that secondary objective (and sometimes there's no such objective, but still a mysterious appearance time).

Comment: It seems that it appears either when you're relatively close, or when the game thinks you're lost.  For instance, it showed up for me once when I was approaching the entrance to another area.

Comment: @MBraedley That sounds like what happened with me in the Howling Plateau. I crossed the bridge (Black Canyon Bridge) and it seemed to pop after that showing me to be back the way I came.

Answer (score 1):

It shows up when u are relatively close to the point u need to be.
This range increases, as you **ACTIVELY** run or slay monsters in the area where the bounty has to be done.

If we go deeper:
As you maybe know, Bounty Reward Experience also scales with time you are playing.
There are different stages of Experience you can get (If i remember right there are 5).

As you progress in the bonus XP you progress in the range the arrow shows up, meaning if you are at bonus stage 1 you need to be very close to get the arrow, if you are at maximum, e.g. 5 you will see the arrow around the whole map.

Comment: Hum interesting theory. Do you have more information about the thresholds etc (or better: sources) ? I don't think it explains completely the situation become sometimes the arrow appears while you're moving away from the objective fast, and not killing anything.

Comment: I don't have a source, but I have done about 2 hours in testing this.
In my Test i didn't get the arrow while doing nothing (standing in town), maybe it works if you are doing nothing or moving away in these areas.
About the thresholds i couldn't find any specific number, as it seems to need more time if the area, or the bounty target is larger/needs longer to complete than if the area is smaller.

Additionally i found out the default range where the arrow shows up seems proportionate bigger in bigger areas (e.g. 100m area -> 10m close: arrow shows, 500m area -> 50m close: arrow shows.

Answer (score -1):

By my own testing it seems to be about the time, if you just wait for 30 - 50 seconds the minimap objective marker seems to appear.